# PHP: How to dump all local variables in an exception handler

Tags: php

I'm looking for a method of having my exception handler dump the local variables of the function which the exception was raised in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

`get_defined_vars()` will return an array of all defined variables. You can then loop through each one and dump the contents, or use `var_dump( get_defined_vars() )` to dump them en masse.

Comment: That's correct, however it's good to note that this will not be exactly exception handler code. You would have to be resopnsible to supply these to the exception while throwing the exception. This being said, I don't know of any way you can accomplish the same in the exception handling itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try `var_dump( get_defined_vars(  ) );`. That should dump all defined variables in scope.

Answer (score 2):

I think better is to setup [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/).

It dumps all environment automaticly.

And you will get everytime something like:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to RogoDeal::getDealerForMe() must be an instance of RogoParticipant, instance of myUser given in G:\webroot\v1-1-5.omyconf\lib\model\doctrine\RogoDeal.class.php on line 512

Call Stack:
    0.0002     336944   1. {main}() G:\webroot\v1-1-5.omyconf\web\frontend_dev.php:0
    0.1244    1983360   2. sfContext->dispatch() G:\webroot\v1-1-5.omyconf\web\frontend_dev.php:13
    0.1244    1983392   3. sfFrontWebController->dispatch() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\util\sfContext.class.php:170
    0.1248    1987104   4. sfController->forward() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\controller\sfFrontWebController.class.php:48
    0.1500    2085896   5. sfFilterChain->execute() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\controller\sfController.class.php:238
    0.1504    2086752   6. sfRenderingFilter->execute() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php:53
    0.1504    2086752   7. sfFilterChain->execute() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfRenderingFilter.class.php:33
    0.1508    2087584   8. sfBasicSecurityFilter->execute() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php:53
    0.1512    2087584   9. sfFilterChain->execute() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfBasicSecurityFilter.class.php:72
    0.1515    2088408  10. sfCacheFilter->execute() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php:53
    0.1549    2089920  11. sfFilterChain->execute() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfCacheFilter.class.php:65
    0.1553    2090744  12. sfExecutionFilter->execute() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php:53
   14.8569   19778472  13. sfExecutionFilter->handleView() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfExecutionFilter.class.php:47
   14.8570   19778472  14. sfExecutionFilter->executeView() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfExecutionFilter.class.php:116
   14.8662   19806016  15. sfPHPView->render() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\filter\sfExecutionFilter.class.php:155
   14.8673   19806352  16. sfPHPView->renderFile() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\view\sfPHPView.class.php:185
   14.8801   19926728  17. require('G:\webroot\v1-1-5.omyconf\apps\frontend\modules\program\templates\markedSuccess.php') G:\webroot\symfony\lib\view\sfPHPView.class.php:75
   16.2403   21796104  18. sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator->getDealerForMe() G:\webroot\v1-1-5.omyconf\apps\frontend\modules\program\templates\markedSuccess.php:48
   16.2403   21796304  19. sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator->__call() G:\webroot\v1-1-5.omyconf\apps\frontend\modules\program\templates\markedSuccess.php:48
   16.2404   21796552  20. call_user_func_array() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator.class.php:64
   16.2404   21796736  21. RogoDeal->getDealerForMe() G:\webroot\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator.class.php:64

Dump $_SERVER
   $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET'
   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/frontend_dev.php/program/marked?interface=mobile'
   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; Edition Ukraine Local; ru) Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.60'
Dump $_REQUEST
   $_REQUEST['interface'] = 'mobile'

Variables in local scope (#21):
  $dealer = *uninitialized*
  $me = *uninitialized*
  $owner = *uninitialized*
```

It makes incredibly easy debug.

Answer (score 2):

The exception handler will never have access to the local variables of the function which the exception raised because those variables are local. I do not think there is a way to obtain access to the variable table of a specific stack frame from userland PHP code.

You can do this by using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) as a step debugger. With breakpoints (e.g. in the exception handler) you are able to look into each stack frame.

Next to step debugging, there are also some display options you might want to make use of, like:

- http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace#add-local-vars

Answer (score 2):

You have access to local variables, if the exception will be caught in the same scope/function it is thrown:

```
<?php

try
{
    $var = 123;
    throw new Exception();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($var); // int(123)
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have all defined (including predefined) by calling function **get_defined_vars**.

Just local variables (scope of current function) is not available without some debugging tools.